# Schedule automated jobs in Django

Tags: python, django, django-cron, django-scheduler

Anyone knows how to schedule a Django script to run at a certain date and time?

Example:

User enters someone’s contact info on frontend, Django backend receives the form data, but doesn’t send the contact an email until 48 hours later.

Anyone has an idea? I saw Cron, but looks like Cron needs to be executed and doesn’t automatically execute on its own? Just need help learning the scheduling feature.

Answer (score 1):

**Install django-crontab using the below command**

```
 pip install django-crontab
```

**In your django project’s settings.py file,**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django_crontab',
...
]
```

**Create a file anywhere within your django’s project, for e.g. myapp/cron.py and define the function which you want to be executed automatically via cron**

```
def my_cron_job():
    # your functionality goes here
```

**Add the following line to your django project’s settings.py file**
[ This is the every two minute cron job]

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/2 * * * *', 'myapp.cron.my_cron_job')
]
```

**Add all the defined CRONJOBS**

```
python manage.py crontab add
```

**To get all the active CRONJOBS**

```
python manage.py crontab show
```

**To remove all the defined CRONJOBS**

```
python manage.py crontab remove
```

**To list all active cron**

```
crontab -l
```

Comment: I am looking for something that is triggered within my code.

Example:

User submits a form in frontend 

Form data hits backend and trigger an automation

***automation does this***
Wait for 24 hours before running this set of code that will send email out to the user who filled the form

24 hours later….

Django sends email to the user.

Looks like Cron requires a conmand to be activated and is not always running?
Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some background task manager and scheduler.

[Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) is for managing and execution tasks and [Celery Beat](https://pypi.org/project/django-celery-beat/) will help to schedule the periodic tasks or cron and will be executed at given time.